# EO Webbrowser Run Javascript

Tags: c#, eo.webbrowser

I am looking for the equivalent code using EO Webbrowser control

```
HtmlElement hElement = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement sElement = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
sElement.InnerText = javascript5;
hElement.AppendChild(sElement);

ImageCallBack cb = new ImageCallBack();
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("getImage", new object[] { cb });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
_Browser.EvalScript(script);
_Browser.InvokeFunction(functionName, args);
```

Answer to the question i asked.

Comment: And, what is with these 2 lines of code? Is this an answer, or another comment to your question ?

Comment: Answer to the question i asked